# Remove pattern from a large file (~1G)

Tags: regex, linux, text, replace, sed

I am trying to remove this pattern from a file `/([0-9]+)#(\w)+.(\w)+.(\w)+.(\w)+.(\w)+#/g`
I am using `sed` (but I can use any other tools that come in Linux).

```
sed 's|/([0-9]+)#(\w)+.(\w)+.(\w)+.(\w)+.(\w)+#/g||g' test.txt
```

In the command above I am trying to replace regex matches with an empty string (remove regex match)
Running this doesn't make any changes in the file.

Here is what I have in the file test.txt

```
3149177#sometext.something.a01234.e8f933.1414522190425#{....}3149177#sometext.somethingElsea.a12345.e8f932.1414412190425#{.....}3149177#sometext.somethingElsea.a23456.e8f931.1414512190425#{....}
```

And here is what I would like to have after editing

```
{....}{.....}{....}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have extra delimiters and `g` flags. This works:

```
sed -i.bak -r 's|([0-9]+)#(\w)+.(\w)+.(\w)+.(\w)+.(\w)+#||g' test.txt
{....}{.....}{....}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can probably reduce the regex to this:

`sed -i.bak -r 's/\d+#\w+(?:\.\w+){4}#//g' test.txt`

```
 \d+ 
 \# \w+ 
 (?: \. \w+ ){4}
 \#
```

Answer (score 0):

you forgot the `-i` flag to sed, which is responsible for edit-in-place

quote from man (BSD sed):

```
 -i extension
         Edit files in-place, saving backups with the specified extension.  If a zero-length extension is given, no backup will be saved.  It is not recommended to give a zero-length extension when in-place editing files, as you risk corruption or par-
         tial content in situations where disk space is exhausted, etc.
```

or GNU sed:

```
 -i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]
          edit files in place (makes backup if SUFFIX supplied)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like

```
>>> echo "3149177#sometext.something.a01234.e8f933.1414522190425#{....}3149177#sometext.somethingElsea.a12345.e8f932.1414412190425#{.....}3149177#sometext.somethingElsea.a23456.e8f931.1414512190425#{....}" | sed -r 's/([0-9]+)#(\w)+.(\w)+.(\w)+.(\w)+.(\w)+#//g'
```

will give output as

```
{....}{.....}{....}
```

Answer (score 0):

If removing the line instead of empty line is a possible solution

```
fgrep -v '/([0-9]+)#(\w)+.(\w)+.(\w)+.(\w)+.(\w)+#/g' test.txt
```